# How can I fix the onfocus quotations this.id inside a Javascript HTML function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td><input type='date' class='form-control'></td><td><input type='time' class='form-control'></td><td><input type='time' class='form-control'></td><td><input onfocus='this.id='client-search' type='text' class='form-control'><ul class='livesearch' id='client-result' onclick='clickResult()'></ul></td>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++; 
    });
```

How can I fix the quotation inside the onfocus event? Thank you.

Comment: You can use `onfocus='this.id=\"'client-search\"'`, However as you are creating element with `id='client-result'` in in click event handler, it will create element with duplicate ID. This will render HTML as invalid. Note: __Identifiers in HTML must be unique.__

Comment: Separate your JavaScript *(jQuery in this case)* from your HTML, unless you like escaping Strings. Why would you use jQuery then have HTML String functions? Please.

Answer (score 0):

When using “strings within strings” one reaches a point where the quote characters need to be escaped.
You can take a look at this in practice here https://jsfiddle.net/z6w3juj4/1/
But in essence, you would need to do something like the following:

```
"<div class='btn' onclick='this.innerHTML = \"clicked\"'>click here</div>"
```

With escaped quotes `\" \"` around the ‘deeper’ strings.

Hope that helps!